# Cakephp 3 customize password column to use _setPassword method in Model?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a column in the database with the name `PASS` that stores the password. It needs to go through the _setPassword method for hashing. but by default it will only go through that method if the column name is `password`, how do I make `PASS` to go through that `_setPassword` method like `password`?

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
/**
 * DefaultUser Entity.
 */
class DefaultUser extends Entity
{

    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'first_name' => true,
        'last_name' => true,
        'email' => true,
        'PASS' => true,
        'active' => true,
    ];


    protected function _setPassword($password) {
        $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
        return $hasher -> hash($password);
    }

}
```

Note: this is cakephp 3.0 code.

Comment: Can you not define a mutator with the correct name? (I don't know what CakePHP will think of the uppercase `PASS` as opposed to `pass` but `protected function _setPass($password)`?

Comment: Alternatively, can you not rename your database column to `password` or at least downcase it according to CakePHP convention as `pass` rather than `PASS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the correct name for the entity setter:

```
protected function _setPASS($password) {
    $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
    return $hasher->hash($password);
}
```

Comment: if am using column with name like that `user_password`, so what i should to use?
I tried:
`_setUser_password`,`_setUserPassword` ,`_setUser_Password`,`_set_user_password`

Comment: @machel : it seems to work with _setUserPassword